# Running Kotlin Scripts (.kts) with bindings from IntelliJ - unresolved reference: bindings

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, java-scripting-engine

I am trying to run **.kts** scripts (using Script Engine) from a Kotlin program.

The Kotlin scripts reside in the resource folder of the project and normally they have support for auto-completion, IDE checks, auto-complete, etc.

The problem appeared when I wanted to pass external variables to the script using bindings. I am doing something like:

```
scriptEngine.eval(scriptContent, scriptEngine.createBindings().apply { putAll(bindings) })
```

The `bindings` is a `Map<String, Any>` that contains the variables I want to access in my script: `bindings["variable"]`.

Problem is that IntellIJ doesn't recognize `bindings` in the .kts script, so it shows a "unresolved reference: bindings". If I run the script from command line everything is fine, but inside IntelliJ i have this problem.

Is there a way to overcome the issue ? Has any experienced the same problem?

Comment: Can you please create an issue at http://kotl.in/issue with a sample project to reproduce, so we can investigate it and offer a workaround if possible?

Comment: @AndreiCiobanu Have you resolved your problem somehow?

Comment: @user3159253 no :(. But I don't use bindings anymore.

Comment: Do you still run Kotlin Scripts? What approach have you chosen?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/nomemory/mapneat/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/net/andreinc/mapneat/experimental/scripting/KotlinScriptRunner.kt